# How to display the hostname name in screen when you ssh into remote system?

Tags: unix, gnu-screen

I have various systems to which i regularly ssh into . The problem is  , at some point of time i forget the hostname into which i have ssh into. Its kinda tedious to keep checking hostname all the time. Is it possible to display the hostname in screen (  i use screen to ssh into remote machines ) .

For example

```
$screen  
$ssh hostname.com
```

after i ssh , in my screen the current hostname is displayed.

Comment: Search for info about .screenrc file. It will let you 'launch' all the windows you want, and you can specify (hard-code), something like `-T window title (i.e. hostname)`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

put this in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

`PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033k$HOSTNAME\033\\"'`

Comment: Can you explain how this works so we can modify it ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

Does the "hostname" command work?

I suspect your solution will be terminal program specific. What is your terminal client? Take a look at http://kpumuk.info/mac-os-x/how-to-show-ssh-host-name-on-the-iterms-background/ .

Comment: well that was just an example to ssh into system. i dint mean it as hostname cmd. sry if i wasnt clear .